# How can I parse a char buffer in C?

Tags: c

So this is the char buffer I have:

```
Manual: h:0147(0051.6) v:0842(0296.0) H:0114(0040.0) V:0697(0245.0)
```

Please note that this buffer is **not certain to be null terminated**.

What I want to do is to get the last two numbers from the parentheses `()`.

I was gonna use a `sscanf()` like this:

```c
sscanf(buffer, "H:%4d(%f) V:%4d(%f)", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4);
```

But I believe that it is not possible, because it is not null terminated?

How could I possibly get these two float numbers out of it to use later?

One way would be, since the buffer is still the same size and format, only the numbers change, to just use index to get it, but I think there must be a better way.

Comment: Do you know the length of the buffer? You could copy it into another array and add the null terminator.

Comment: That `sscanf()` won't work because `H` is in the middle of the buffer, not at the beginning. `sscanf()` won't search for the first match to the format string.

Comment: Possibly, yes, that would be a solution. The size is still the same, as well as the format. 

I guess that I should just do it like that and then the sscanf would be a fine solution?

Comment: @Barmar you can use `sscanf(buffer, "%*[^H]H...", ...)` to ignore everything up to the first `H`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good solution.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. 

So, null terminating the buffer and then using the suggested to ignore the beginning. WIll try, thanks for help guys!

Comment: @t0is is the number of `H` and `V` values fixed?  Will there always be 2 `H`s and 2 `V`s per `buffer`?  If not, then you will need to call `sscanf()` in a loop, scanning a different section of the `buffer` on each iteration.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, the format is still like this. Exactly the same. Your solution worked like charm, thanks for the help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Barmar and @RemyLebeau for the help.

The solution to the problem is the following

```
sscanf(buffer, "%*[^H]H:%4d(%f) V:%4d(%f)", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4);
```

Works like charm